# Set sitecore treelist datasource from multiple paths

Tags: datasource

Trying to set datasource for a treelist field in Sitecore. Need to set two different folders as path.

```
DataSource=/sitecore/content/home/folder1|/sitecore/content/home/folder2
```

It does not work, it sets home node as starting path.

Also tried IncludeTemplatesForSelection=template1,template2

```
Datasource=/sitecore/content/home&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=template1,template2
```

Answer (score 6):

I can think of two options to solve your issue:

1. Create some custom code to make a "query" possible together in the datasource. Luckily for you that is already been done and well [documented](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/01/06/specifying-query-and-parameters-for-sitecore-treelist-field-source/). Unfortunately as Jammykam correctly pointed out, this won't completely fix your as the `TreeList` can only accept one parent node. So this would actually come down to a complex version of option2. You could however try to write your own field (based upon a treelist), but that might take some more customization. But you're lucky again! There is another Kam, and he shared some code to do exactly that: a [multi-root treelist](http://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/05/A-Multiple-Root-Treelist-Field/).
2. Use the ootb options, with one path but by using the `IncludeTemplatesForDisplay` and `IncludeTemplatesForSelection`. This might get a good result, but it depends on the templates used in folder1 and folder2. Assuming your template1 and template2 are used for folder1 and folder2 (and no others on that level), you could set `Datasource=/sitecore/content/home&IncludeTemplatesForDisplay=template1,template2,datasourcetemplate&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=datasourcetemplate`. Note that I included datasourcetemplate (the template of the source you want to be selected) in templates to display and to select (to make them visible and selectable).

> Remark: option "1" was edited after jammykam's comments (thx for the
>   correction). I'll kept part of the text to make the comments not
>   completely weird. And then shifted the solution from one kam to the
>   other :)

Comment: Option one will not work with a `Treelist` control, since it only supports a single item as root node. Supplying multiple item list would require customisation to the control.

Comment: Must admit I didn't try it, but your blogpost is titled "Specifying query and parameters for Sitecore Treelist Field Source"? (I did mention custom code was necessary though)

Comment: Yes but that blog post is solving a different problem (xpath query **and** template restrictions). The issue is the treelist control can only have one root node, unlike multilist for example which is a flat structure. So no idea how you solve specifying multiple source root nodes in this instance...

Comment: Ah ok, now I see what you mean ;) And you're right - I'll adapt the answer.

Comment: I actually wrote a blog post back in June that combined the Kam Figy and JammyKam posts that you linked to and does exactly what the OP is asking for. Both of those posts were great references! +1 and here is the post I wrote, for reference: http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2016/june/06/creating-a-multi-root-treelist-field-in-sitecore

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote a [blog post](http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2016/june/06/creating-a-multi-root-treelist-field-in-sitecore) on this same issue a while back, and my solution combines both [JammyKam's](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/01/06/specifying-query-and-parameters-for-sitecore-treelist-field-source/) and [Kamsar's](http://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/05/A-Multiple-Root-Treelist-Field/) solutions (the ones linked to in @Gatogordo's post) and implements exactly what you are looking for and more.

*Note that I am currently using the code in my post on a production site.*

#### Overview

Sitecore's Treelist field is an excellent way to select items that live under a common root node, but it doesn't support multiple roots. To support multiple roots, you will need to create your own field type.

[My post](http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2016/june/06/creating-a-multi-root-treelist-field-in-sitecore) will show you how, and includes support for Datasource Parameters (Include/Exclude from Template/Display, etc.) and also adds support for using Datasource Parameters with Sitecore Query (which isn't supported OOTB). It even allows you to mix and match query and non-query datasources, e.g. `/sitecore/content/home/foo/bar|query:./[@@templateid='{...}]`. In addition, it will also show you how you can override the display of the field to show the path to each item in the selection pane, in order to better support multiple roots with the same name without confusing the content authors.

#### Considerations

Before you start developing, there are a few things that you need to consider:

1. If you're displaying multiple roots then you need to customize the
   view so that the content author can see the paths to the elements.
   Since roots may have the same name, the name of the root may not be
   meaningful enough.
2. The default Treelist shows the root /Sitecore
   node if the root was not found. However, since we're going to be
   showing multiple roots, it's likely better to instead hide the node
   if the root was not found.
3. If you're planning to use this on a
   solution with content search and you want to index this field type,
   you will need to add it to your index configuration.

#### Details

My post is too long to repeat everything here, but basically what you need to do is override the logic for parsing the datasource and applying the datasource parameters, and then use a derived version of the `MultiRootTreeview` class to render the field. See [my post](http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2016/june/06/creating-a-multi-root-treelist-field-in-sitecore) for more details, the code, and thorough explanations of the different pieces that need customization.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some complex logic to load in items in Multilist, treelist etc.. I have a good suggestion for it.
Better create your own datasource with the help of "code:" query. It will hit your backend code and you can load your items in Sitecore multilist.

I found very useful source here.

https://horizontal.blog/2015/04/02/sitecore-source-field-code-query-that-implements-idatasource/

Answer (score 0):

Hi @tomacat you could use PowerShell query as a data source, so I think it will give you more granular control for conditional logic

Please check the ref: video here, hope it helps
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvH6CgUv-lg