# Multiple root nodes for DropTree

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, sitecore-query

I am using SXA and have multiple sites, I want `DropTree` to have two data sourcesas below.

```
/sitecore/content/Tenant1/SiteFolder/LocalSite1/Data/SomeFolder
/sitecore/content/GlobalSite/Data/SomeFolder
```

I have many sites that has same folder structure but I want to show only those folders, as roots  that are either in GlobalSite or in the same site as context item.

I saw similar question has been asked [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3482/droptree-with-multiple-datasources#) but I don't want data from all the sites, I tried their solution as to get started using below query

```
Datasource=query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Site']/Data/SomeFolder
```

I am not able to see multiple root nodes. It shows me entire hierarchy, right from Sitecore node.

[image]

My Context Item is nested under multiple folders.

**Update:**
I tried this query (using pipe operator) too based on [Sitecore Documentations](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/SdnArchive/Reference/Using%20Sitecore%20Query/Sitecore%20Query%20Syntax.html) but still it is not working

```
query:$site/Data/SomeFolder|/sitecore/content/GlobalSite/Data/SomeFolder
```

Comment: @MarekMusielak no, I tried that solution but still facing problems, I have mentioned that in question

Comment: It's still the same question however. If you've implemented as directed, raise a question about any specific problems you have in that implementation.